# What is the recommended way to get a Shopware 6 entity by ID?

Tags: data-access-layer, shopware

I have a entity ID and want to get the Entity object via repository, currently we do

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $propertyId));

    $property = $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->search(
        $criteria,
        $this->context
    )->first();

    if($property) {
        return $property->get('groupId');
    }
```

Is there  a nicer way, like Laravel's `find` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already mentioned in your own answer you can pass the IDs as a parameter to the Criteria object.

I suggest `$property = $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->search(new Criteria([$propertyId]), $context)->first()`

A find method isn't implemented and I assume never will, cause you may want to load use some associations and/or aggragations.

Answer (score 0):

It is at least possible to create a criteria with an ID filter without creating an Equals filter.

The shopware core does it like this:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->search(new Criteria([$productId]), $context)->get($productId);
```

So for the above example it would be

```
$property = $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository
    ->search(new Criteria([$propertyId]), $context)->get($propertyId);
```

Comment: IMHO using the `first()` function is "nicer": `$product = $this->productRepository->search(new Criteria([$productId]), $context)->first();`. But there is no equivalent to Laravel's `find` function. You have to use repositories and criteria.

Comment: Yep there is no buit in `find()` function, but you should always prefer this solution which injects the Ids into the Criteria-Objects constructor, as the runtime behaviour is slightly different and using the criteria this way should be faster then using an EqualsFilter, due to internals on how those filters get resolved